# Error while installing ffpyplayer on Raspberry Pi OS using pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, ffpyplayer

I tried installing ffpyplayer on raspberry pi os using the command:

```
pip3 install ffpyplayer
```

But i get this huge error, and it stops the installation.
I couldnt paste the error in SO since it exceeds the character limit, her is the error:[Error](https://pastebin.com/BLVYUZES)

I tried doing [Installation doc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) from this [Github Issue](https://github.com/matham/ffpyplayer/issues/22), but i get an error while installing libv1d.

I dont understand this error. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Requirements: https://matham.github.io/ffpyplayer/installation.html#requirements

Comment: When i try installing SDL2 libraries using sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
I get another error saying 404 Not Found Error and Failed to fetch errror